# Wait for async .done() in every iteration of loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, typescript, es6-promise

So, I have function that locks like this:

```
function getMainData() {
    var dfd = $.Deferred();

    $.getJSON('My string that i pass',
        function(result) {
            if (result !== undefined) {
                dfd.resolve(result);
            }
        })

    return dfd.promise()
}

function getSpecificData() {
    var dfd = $.Deferred();

    var myArray = [];

    for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        getMainData().done(function(result) {
            myArray.push(result)

            dfd.resolve(myArray) //This is where I am lost.
        })
    }

    return dfd.promise()
}

getSpecificData().done(function(result) {
    console.log(result);
})
```

I think I know how promises work if you chain them together but I can not make the for-loop to wait for the async call to finish before the next iteration.

Can some please help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A for loop has no means of delaying the next iteration to wait for asynchronous code.

You can solve it by using a function that is called recursively instead

```
function getMainData() {
    return $.getJSON('My string that i pass');
}

function getSpecificData() {
    var myArray = [], def = new $.Deferred();

    (function rec(i) {
        getMainData().done(function(result) {
            myArray.push(result);
            if (i < 5 && result !== undefined) {
                console.log(i)
                rec(++i);
            } else {
                def.resolve(myArray);
            }
        });
    })(0);

    return def.promise();
}

getSpecificData().done(function(result) {
    console.log(result);
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution, this worked out well, and I was actually not thinking about recursive methods.

Answer (score 1):

You should instead push all promises into an array and wait for all to finish.

```
function getMainData() {
    return $.getJSON('My string that i pass');
}

function getSpecificData() {
    var promiseArray = [];

    for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        promiseArray.push(getMainData());
    }

    return $.when.apply($, promiseArray);
}

getSpecificData().done(function(result) {
    console.log(result);
})
```

Comment: Thanks for a nice solution, but this is not working as intended. I am not getting values from all my async calls. That means the loop is not waiting for the async call.

Comment: @Zorken17 You can use arguments variable to get full return list instead of result variable

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried without `promise` like :

```
var myArray = [];
var cpt=0;
var total=5;

getMainData();
console.log(myArray);

function getMainData() 
{
    $.getJSON('My string that i pass', function(result) {
        if(cpt<total)
        {
            myArray.push(result);
            cpt++;

            getMainData();
        }
    })
}
```

Hope this helps.